# Can't find all the free space in EC2 volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, space, volume

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11606
loop1     7:1    0   25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop2     7:2    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop3     7:3    0 99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11420
loop4     7:4    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop5     7:5    0 33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
xvda    202:0    0   10G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   10G  0 part /
```

As you can see I should hav3 10G mounted here, I know that I need to have a lot of space left since I have just increased my volume on AWS.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            98M   11M   88M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/loop0      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11606
/dev/loop1       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop3      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop5       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
```

> ```
> sudo fdisk
> sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxxxx: Resource temporarily unavailable
> ```

As you can see, only 8.2GB is used here, I don't know where the last 1.8GB are, I need to add them to "/"

Ubuntu
Linux/UNIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxxxx: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

this issue was unrelated, I fixed it by updating the DNS config.

As for the lost volume, it appeared once I rebooted the server.